# Primes 5 mod 8 can be written in the form $(2x+y)^2 + 4y^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I am stuck trying to prove the theorem using an algebraic approach, please could someone give me a hint(preferably not the whole answer)

> Primes 5 mod 8 can be written in the form $(2x+y)^2 + 4y^2$

I am told to assume and make use of the fact that primes 1 mod 4 can be written as $p=m^2+n^2$. WLOG I let $m^2$ be even and $n$ be odd($m=2a, n^2=8q+1$) So,

$$8k+5= (2a)^2+(8q+1)$$
$$\iff 8(k-q)+4=4a^2$$
$$\iff 2(k-q)+1 = a^2$$
$$\implies a=2v+1$$
$$2(k-q)+1=4v^2+4v+1$$
$$(k-q)=2v(v+1)$$

At this point I feel completely lost and alienated from my original goal. I can say that 4|k-q but I don't think this is useful. Could someone give me a nudge in the right direction?

Comment: What you want is to write $n^2 = (2x + a)^2$. To do that, you need to know that $a$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $(2x+y)^2 + 4y^2 = 4(x^2+xy)+5y^2$.

$y$ has to be odd for the expression to be a prime number. Now regardless of $x$ is odd or even, what happens to $x^2+xy$? Also if $y$ is odd, $5y^2$ can be written $5(2n+1)^2 = 20(n^2 + n) + 5$